# Can I do something about the hounds?

Tags: dont-starve

Is there some easy way, cheating or otherwise, to stop the hounds from attacking so often/strong? I am on day 150, and every 5 days or so they break all my armour and nearly kill me. And don't get me started on winter or night attacks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get **warnings** when a Hound attack is imminent in the form of growling sounds. Your character will also make a comment to that effect. When they appear, the growling sounds are replaced by panting and running sounds.

Best way to counter hounds is to build **walls** so that there is only one entrance and path that leads to the player. Line this path with **tooth traps**, and hounds will kill themselves when they run over trying to reach you.

You can also stand near **beefalo herds** (not in heat) because hounds target any living creatures nearby when they bark. Beefalos can quickly dispatch hounds and you can farm items off of both as long as you pick up the items before they burn. Same strategy if you are near a **marsh**,**killer bee hives** or **frog ponds**, **pig village**, **tallbirds**, etc.

If you are alone, try to prepare. A **better weapon** than a spear, a **helmet** and some **armor** work wonders. Manage your **inventory** so you're carrying what's necessary (grass, twigs, flint, wood, food, healing, sanity, heat stone, weapon, extra armor).

If you are alone and haven't prepared, then you have to fight smart. When a hound bites, it pauses for a brief moment. You can **dodge** the bite and **hit twice** during this period.

If you are unprepared to fight and decide to **run**, then use a walking cane or use a road. Otherwise, a hound has faster move-speed than you and you might be chased down. Don't forget to build a torch or two in advance so you won't be surprised by night!

Comment: And to answer question about stopping hounds from attacking entirely, I don't think it's possible in your current playthrough. You can select the option of no hounds when creating a new game though.

Comment: I have all of that, this is a good answer. I am too new to DS to use the pro fighting tactic, and i get too many hounds anyway. I am worried my beefalos will die out, but it seems like a good solution. Nice one!

Comment: Note: You can be near beefalos in heat when wearing the beefalo hat.

Comment: Note also that large numbers of hounds can decimate beefalo, tallbird, beehive, or pig populations. Only lead a group of hounds to these if you can afford to lose a few.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of different strategies you can use, but here's a relatively easy one: Tame some **Treeguards**.

Set up a fire pit away from your main base where you can go to deal with hound attacks.  (You don't want to use your main base because fire hounds might burn it down.)

Chop trees somewhere nearby until you awake a Treeguard.  Lead it to the fire pit, and then plant trees near it until you pacify it.  Repeat as often as you like until you have a Treeguard army you're comfortable with.  This can also help with boss monsters such as the Deerclops; two Treeguards are more than a match for a Deerclops even if he frequently freezes them.

Comment: Ohh this is great! I had a few tree guards, but well... You know tentacle fields? It didn't. Rock lobsters got the other one. Also, i killed a deercyclops with a tentacle field, just as a bit of random trivia.

Comment: Oh, also, I am not accepting this answer because it only has one answer, I was hoping for a list. It is still a great tactic, and I did upvote it!